# parseFloat function does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

I need to validate textbox entry. It should allow only integers as entityframework fails if user enters characters in this field during binding.

Here is problem:

When user enters `10-d` in this field, `parseFloat` returns `true` as it takes `10` as number and ignores the rest of values. While IMO it should throw NAN error as input text can not be converted to float.

Please see following samples and you can play with it.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat

The one i am interested it to get NAN for 40 Years input in examples above.

```
document.write(parseFloat("40 years") + "<br />");
```

Let me know if i need to do some more verification.

Comment: Use `$.isNumeric('10-d');` or `$.isNumeric('10 years')` both wil return false.

Comment: If  you want integers try `parseInt("string",10)`. The second param is the radix which tells it what number base to use. In this case, base 10.

Comment: Actually `parseFloat('10-d')` returns `10` rather than `true`. Visit http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.3 to see how `parseFloat()` works.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use the `isNaN` function.

```
isNaN('40'); //false, as '40' is a number
isNaN('40 years'); //true, as '40 years' is not a number
```

**Update**

As noted, this does not check for integers. For that, you could use

```
function isInt(value) { 
  return !isNaN(value) && value % 1 === 0; 
}
```

This would return true for "40", 40, "40." and false for "40-d", "40.12", 40.12, "40 years".

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/3GfYY/1/)

If you don't want a trailing decimal, then the @jakeclarkson's regex solution is better

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to allow **integers** then you could use:

```
function isInteger(str) {
    return /^[0-9]*$/.test(str);
}
```

`isNaN` will return `false` if you provide it with a decimal, i.e.

```
isNaN("3.14"); // false, i.e. it is a number
```

Whereas the `isInteger()` `function` above will work correctly, i.e.

```
isInteger("3.14"); // false
```